# devise for rails with angular js on front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

```
$http({
     method:'POST',
     url: '/users',
     data: JSON.stringify(user),
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
   })
```

I am using the above method for registering new users using devise. 
 There are no errors on the console however I am getting `rollback_transaction` and I can't figure out whats happening.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-18 19:10:59 +0545
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"email"=>"my_user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "registration"=>{"email"=>"my_user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: its because the csrf token is issing

Comment: i am using angular_rails_csrf gem for the csrf token.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `Devise::RegistrationsController` expects parameters of the form `{ "user" : {"email"=>"my_user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]" }`. In your case when it (create action in RegistrationsController) tries to create new user, it passes empty hash into `User.create` method.

Wrap your http data in another hash with key `user` and value 'user'. Like this:

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/users',
     data: JSON.stringify({ user: user }),
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
   })
```